# Three.js - Animation is not playing

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender, skeletal-mesh

I have problem with animating object exported via [blender plugin](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/utils/exporters/blender) from blender to THREE.js. Animation did not start running...

Of course, I tried many combinations of settings when exporting from blender and importing to THREE.js library, but without success.

Here is code, what I think should work. Comment **Critical section** annotate where is probably some mistake. Link to source JSON is in the example too. Of course, I can provide source *.blend file, if needed...

```js
var tgaLoader = new THREE.TGALoader();
var objectLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();

var clock = new THREE.Clock();

var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
var SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });

renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

objectLoader.load('//cdn.rawgit.com/PiranhaGreg/files/master/scavenger.json', function (loadedScene) {
  scene = loadedScene;
  mesh = scene.children[0];

  scene.background = new THREE.Color('white');
  mesh.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: tgaLoader.load('//cdn.rawgit.com/PiranhaGreg/files/master/SCA_BODY_V0.TGA') });

  hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight('white', 'white', 0.6);
  scene.add(hemiLight);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(30, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.set(500, 200, -100);

  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
  controls.target.set(0, 50, 0);
  controls.update();

  var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(200, 200);
  var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ shininess: 0.1 });
  var ground = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  ground.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;

  scene.add(ground);

  mesh.scale.set(-1, -1, 1);

  // Critical section...
  mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(mesh);
  var sequence = THREE.AnimationClip.CreateFromMorphTargetSequence('animation', mesh.geometry.morphTargets, 25, true);
  var animation = mixer.clipAction(sequence);
  animation.play();
  // End of critital section

  animate();
});

window.onresize = function() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
};

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
}

function render() {
  var delta = 0.75 * clock.getDelta();
  mixer.update(delta);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/87/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/loaders/TGALoader.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: and another model from examples works? https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_keyframes_json

Comment: Just in case, if it helps ) [Workflow: Animation from Blender to three.js](http://unboring.net/workflows/animation.html), with a project on Github.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dug in into animation and noticed that it uses `morphTargets`. And then I remembered about this [example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_morphtargets.html). So, the key moment is to set `.morphTarget` parameter of a material to `true`, so, I've applied it to the material in  your code snippet and it started to work:

```
mesh.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    map: tgaLoader.load('//cdn.rawgit.com/PiranhaGreg/files/master/SCA_BODY_V0.TGA'),
    morphTargets: true
});
```

Though, I'm not sure, if such an approach is correct, but, at least, it's working )

```js
var tgaLoader = new THREE.TGALoader();
var objectLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();

var clock = new THREE.Clock();

var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
var SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });

renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

objectLoader.load('//cdn.rawgit.com/PiranhaGreg/files/master/scavenger.json', function (loadedScene) {
  scene = loadedScene;
  mesh = scene.children[0];

  scene.background = new THREE.Color('white');
  mesh.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: tgaLoader.load('//cdn.rawgit.com/PiranhaGreg/files/master/SCA_BODY_V0.TGA'), morphTargets: true });

  hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight('white', 'white', 0.6);
  scene.add(hemiLight);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(30, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.set(500, 200, -100);

  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
  controls.target.set(0, 50, 0);
  controls.update();

  var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(200, 200);
  var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ shininess: 0.1 });
  var ground = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  ground.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;

  scene.add(ground);

  mesh.scale.set(-1, -1, 1);

  // Critical section...
  mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(mesh);
  var sequence = THREE.AnimationClip.CreateFromMorphTargetSequence('animation', mesh.geometry.morphTargets, 25, true);
  var animation = mixer.clipAction(sequence);
  animation.play();
  // End of critital section

  animate();
});

window.onresize = function() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
};

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
}

function render() {
  var delta = 0.75 * clock.getDelta();
  mixer.update(delta);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/87/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/loaders/TGALoader.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Big thanks! You just saved me many hours. I was thinking that problem is somewhere between blender -> THREE.js export and completely missed this property.

Comment: :) you're welcome ) I haven't worked with animation before, so it was interesting for myself to solve your problem )